# Unable to start application. Bean Creation Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have tried all other solutions including adding the following in the POM.xml file but could not solve the problem. Please could anyone take a look and advise?

I am also using Swagger plugins in my code if that helps.
Already tried:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
and

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
UPDATE: Or simply add the following dependency.

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

==============================================================

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2021-03-12 13:03:13.874 ERROR 45332 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
        
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:0', transport: 'socket'
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

================================================================

Service POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>proman</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.upgrad.proman</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>proman-service</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

==========================================================================
API POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>proman</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.upgrad.proman</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>proman-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.upgrad.proman</groupId>
            <artifactId>proman-service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <modelPackage>com.upgrad.proman.api.model</modelPackage>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>true</java8>
                            <sourceFolder>.</sourceFolder>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>

                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.18</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-generators</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-rc0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>signup</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/endpoints/signup.json</inputSpec>
                            <language>spring</language>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Had to truncate the error output since StackOverflow didn't allow posting the entire output.

Comment: This is most likely because you are using versions of `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entitymanager` that don't match. Use matching versions.

Comment: @Sujoy Ghosh, Please post full pom.xml

Comment: Remove the hibernate dependencies and add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: @Jesper Can you please elaborate? Sorry, i am new to this.

Comment: @M.Deinum Already using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in my pom.xml

Comment: If that is already there remove the hibernate dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't have explicit hibernate dependencies in POM.xml. I have my Service POM.xml posted. Only have the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

Comment: @Maheshkumar Posted the API and Service POM.xml

Comment: @Jesper I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Posted my POM.xml for your guidance.